# Replacing specific text pattern from paragraph with php

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, design-patterns

I need to replace text starting with 'Title:' and ending with 'Article Body:' using preg_replace or other way. Replaced text will not be contain above quoted words.

eg:

Title:

sample text 1

Article Body:

sample text 2

Should output only

sample text 2

How can I do this with php?

Comment: sounds simple enough. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I know it could be done with preg_replace. But I have no experience with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive/negative lookaheads.

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=Title:).*(?=Article Body:)/s', '\nTest\n', $subject);
```

The above regex will replace whatever is inside Title: ... Article Body: with \nTest\n

**Explanation :**

```
"
(?<=                # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   Title:              # Match the characters “Title:” literally
)
.                   # Match any single character
   *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?=                 # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   Article\ Body:      # Match the characters “Article Body:” literally
)
"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Title: this is sample text Article Body: this is also sample text';

// output: this is sample text this is also sample text
echo preg_replace('~Title: (.*)Article Body: (.*)~', '$1 $2', $str);
```

Regular expressions are very helpful and you should lear how to use it. There are a lot of articles on the web, also this [summarize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPIdv.png)
 can help you.

Comment: thanks! But this is not working. I need to replace this pattern with no text.

Comment: @AmilaPremasiri: Remove the ` $2` from the second parameter.

Comment: Does it work with string literals as the replacement parameter (the `'$1 $2'` bit)? I'd always assumed that would have to be a, well, non-literal string (e.g. `"$1 $2"`).

Comment: Sorry, There should be line downs in text structure. The structure is like this article http://realorscam.com/big-brother-7-%E2%80%93-grace-is-evicted.html